# Finding size of test based on Poisson random variables

Tags: solution-verification, poisson-distribution, hypothesis-testing

**Problem:**

Let $(X,Y)$ be a random sample from the Poisson distribution with unknown mean $\theta$. In order to test $H_0:\theta=1$ against $H_1:\theta >1$, the following procedure is suggested:

If $X\leq 1$, then accept $H_0$.

If $X\geq 4$, then reject $H_0$.

If $X$ equals $2$ or $3$, then reject $H_0$ if $X+Y\geq 4$, otherwise accept $H_0$.

Find the size of the test.

**My attempt:**

$X$ and $Y$ follow $Poisson(1)$ distribution independently.

Size of the test

$=P_{H_0}(X\geq 4)+P_{H_0}(X=2, X+Y\geq 4)+P_{H_0}(X=3, X+Y\geq 4)$

$=P_{H_0}(X\geq 4)+P_{H_0}(X=2, Y\geq 2)+P_{H_0}(X=3, Y\geq 1)$

$=P_{H_0}(X\geq 4)+P_{H_0}(X=2)(Y\geq 2)+P_{H_0}(X=3)(Y\geq 1)$

$=[1-\sum_{x=0}^{3}e^{-1}\frac{1}{x!}]+\frac{e^{-1}}{2}[1-\sum_{y=0}^{1}e^{-1}\frac{1}{x!}]+\frac{e^{-1}}{6}[1-e^{-1}]$

$=0.10635$

I want to know if I have done it correctly, or otherwise, I want to know where the mistake is. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your answer is correct.  The size of the test is the conditional probability of rejecting $H_0$ given that $H_0$ is true.  Since $H_0$ is rejected in exactly two mutually exclusive cases:

1. $X \ge 4$
2. $X \in \{2, 3\}$ and $X + Y \ge 4$

the latter of which can be further broken apart into the two sub-cases you used, then the desired conditional probability is $$\Pr[X \ge 4 \mid H_0] + \Pr[(X = 2) \cap (Y \ge 2) \mid H_0] + \Pr[(X = 3) \cap (Y \ge 1) \mid H_0]$$ which is, apart from minor notational differences, is the same as what you wrote.

As an exercise, how would you calculate the *power curve* for this test?  In other words, given $H_1 : \theta = \theta_1$ for some $\theta_1 \ne 1$, what is the power of this test to reject $H_0$ as a function of $\theta_1$?